# how to set package per application with odbconf for ibm i access odbc driver

Tags: windows, odbc, iseries-navigator

I would like to set IBM i Access odbc with command line on Windows 7 Enterprise 32-bit.

Almost configuration can be set with odbcconf command, referencing to a following site.

[IBM Knowledge Center:  Connection string keywords - Package properties](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaik/rzaikconnstrkeywordspkgprop.htm?lang=en)

But I can't find properties for custom package setting per application.

Is there the way to set custom package per application with odbcconf or other command line tools?

Answer (score 0):

You try make file dsn for IBM i Access odbc.

And this file dsn open Text Editor.

The Parameter in file dsn is to be able to use.

I tried this way informix and success to add dsn by odbcconf.

Maybe, other database is same.